# Does invoking a multicast delegate allocate memory?

Tags: c#, .net, system.reactive

We are considering reworking some of our interfaces to use IObservable, Subject, and Observer (the latter two are in the Reactive extensions) instead of standard .NET events.  Upon looking at the implementation we found that Subject will lock the list of IObservers it needs to call back, then create a new array, copy the IObserver references into that new array, and then invoke them.

When we look at the implementation of MulticastDelegate we can see that the implementation of MulticastDelegate.GetInvocationList also creates a new array, copies the delegates to be invoked into that array, and then invokes them.  What is not clear is if when you invoke a multicast delegate GetInvocationList gets called or if it is handled within the framework in a way that does not allocate memory.  Does invoking a multicast delegate allocate a new array?  Or does the framework handle things so a new array is not allocated when the event is raised?

Our application is very sensitive to memory allocations and latency so we are trying to ensure we won't be allocating more memory on event invokations by moving to the new interfaces.  We will be running some tests internally as well.

Comment: If your app is _that_ sensitive to a small allocation then you'll have other problems.

Comment: This paticular event could be raised thousands of times a second.  While an individual allocation would not cause a problem for our application thousands of small allocations a second might.

Comment: @Dylan Have you executed the code with a profiler and determined that this is consuming a significant amount of your system's resources?  Ensure that you actually have a problem before looking for the solution.

Comment: @Servy - Yes, this code is in one of our application's hot paths.  It is extremely time critical code.  We are at the point of evaluating different approaches so have not been able to profile each approach yet.

Comment: "We are at the point of evaluating different approaches so have not been able to profile each approach yet." - isn't that a case of putting the cart before the horse?!?

Comment: Why are you using (or want to use) subjects?

Answer (score 4):

> What is not clear is if when you invoke a multicast delegate GetInvocationList gets called or if it is handled within the framework in a way that does not allocate memory.

When you invoke a delegate, it does not call `GetInvocationList`.  This is code for working with and inspecting the delegate, not the actual code used to execute the delegate.  The runtime itself actually executes the invocation internally, as it's not actually in the IL.  This is documented in the CLI spec under 8.9.3:

> While, for the most part, delegates appear to be simply another kind of user-defined class, they are tightly controlled. The implementations of the methods are provided by the VES*, not user code.

Basically, the actual invocation is handled internally by the runtime.

* VES == "Virtual Execution System" in the CLI spec, which is term used for the code executing the runtime itself.

Comment: Got it - makes sense.  I assume the runtime does NOT allocate memory when invoking the delgate.  Am I correct in this assumption?

Comment: To make my earlier comment more specific - I assume the runtime does NOT allocate managed memory (for example, a new object array) when invoking the delgate.  If it allocates memory internally that is fine.  I am more concerned about how it allocates in relation to the System.Reactive extensions.

Comment: @Dylan The runtime won't allocate a normal managed array during the execution.  It's internal implementation is free to do whatever it wants, but it's "tightly controlled" and not allocating an array in managed space.

Answer (score 1):

Seems you're looking at the Rx v1.0 implementation. The subject implementation has been completely overhauled in Rx v2.0 to avoid allocations and heavy locking in the invocation path. Similarly, the Rx query pipeline has been revised with the same criterion in mind.

See http://blogs.msdn.com/b/rxteam/archive/2012/03/12/reactive-extensions-v2-0-beta-available-now.aspx for more information about the Rx v2.0 performance improvements. (While this post dates from the beta days, most information applies to the RTM build. A few things have been refined, for the better.)

For subjects specifically, if you have 2 or more observers attached, they generally outperform multicast delegates. With no observer attached, the cost of virtual methods call on the observer outweigh the null-check and invoke pattern used for events. With one observer, we avoid going through an invocation list (~ delegate without the multicast part), but the cost of the virtual call still shows up. With more observers attached, our foreach loop of virtual methods tends to be faster than the machinery behind multicast delegates.

Here's a slightly simplified excerpt (making some parameters constant and removing references to internal types) of our benchmark code straight from the Rx tests:

```
var e = default(Action<int>);
var a = new Action<int>(_ => { });

var s = new Subject<int>();
var n = new NopObserver<int>();

var N = 20;
var M = 10000000;

var sw = new Stopwatch();

for (int i = 0; i < N; i++)
{
    sw.Restart();
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        var f = e;
        if (f != null)
            f(42);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    var t = sw.Elapsed;
    Console.WriteLine("E({0}) = {1}", i, t);

    sw.Restart();
    for (int j = 0; j < M; j++)
    {
        s.OnNext(42);
    }
    sw.Stop();
    var u = sw.Elapsed;
    Console.WriteLine("O({0}) = {1}", i, u);

    var d = u.TotalMilliseconds / t.TotalMilliseconds;
    Console.ForegroundColor = d <= 1 ? ConsoleColor.Green : ConsoleColor.Red;
    Console.WriteLine(d + " - " + GC.CollectionCount(0));
    Console.ResetColor();

    Console.WriteLine();

    e += a;
    s.Subscribe(n);
}
```

On this machine, the first two iterations go red; subsequent iterations (handler count >= 2) show a 20%-35% speedup. All usual warnings about benchmarks like these apply though :-).

Also, keep in mind that overhead of observer wrapping (for safety guarantees) goes down as the pipeline in Rx gets longer. This is because Rx v2.0 carries out internal handshakes between trusted operators, avoiding extra wrapping. Only the final user subscription will be subject to another layer of virtual calls between Rx and the user-supplied observer code, in order to ensure proper exception propagation, etc. In Rx v1.0, a safety net was provided for each operator, adding anywhere between 2 to 4 additional virtual calls for each message flowing through each operator.

In short: if you decide to do any kind of testing, go for Rx v2.0. Performance was the number 1 feature of this release :-).

Answer (score 0):

Ok, after playing around with the test app below I've convinced myself that invoking a MulticastDelegate does NOT allocate managed memory.  If someone knows differently please let me know.

---

```
using System;
using System.Diagnostics;

internal class Program
{
    private static event Action A;

    private static void Method1() {}
    private static void Method2() {}
    private static void Method3() {}

    private static void Main()
    {
        A += Method1;
        A += Method2;
        A += Method3;

        var totalMemory = GC.GetTotalMemory(true);

        while(true)
        {
            A();

            // Uncommenting the line below will cause the Debug.Assert to be hit.
            // var a = new int[] {};

            if (totalMemory != GC.GetTotalMemory(false))
            {
                // Does not get hit unless line above allocating an array is
                // uncommented.
                Debug.Assert(false);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With regards to Rx and allocations; Rx v2.0 had a lot of effort put into it to reduce the number of allocations and locking that was performed. V1 is a great product but has proven to be the place to get 2years worth of industry feedback on the public surface of the API. Once this became clear what the industry needed, the Rx team went away and worked on the internals. From waht I have seen, Bart DeSmet was able to get over 90-95% CPU utilization on a 64way system using Rx. This is an indicator that it was CPU bound and not context switching, locking or IO bound (I cant for the life of me find the post showing it however). i.e. the System was at full utilization for processing Rx queries not dealing with other plumbing.

From my experience using Rx, there are plenty of other things that can catch you out, allocations are not normally one of them. While I appreciate that there are requirements for low latency systems and allocations can cause GC jitter, I assume that you will be building a single threaded pipeline. If not, I would expect the context switching of a multi-threaded app would far outweigh the cost of a GC here and there. In this case of a single-threaded pipeline, the major benefit you will be getting is the ability to compose the Rx operators to build up queries that should be far more readable than dealing with events.

Lastly, I would steer clear of using subjects or the Observer class in your code. Doing so indicates a design flaw. If you find you do start using them, I would suggest sharing your problem space here (or even better on the Official Rx forums http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/rx/threads) and the community can provide better guidance.